# PHP: Change preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Hello i try to remove "@" from link how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
$string = "@username";   
$mention_url = $WebsiteURL. "/". "\\0";
$string = preg_replace("/(?<!\S)@([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/", "<a href='$mention_url'>\\0</a>", $string);
```

Defualt link is :

```
http://localhost/@username
```

i like this (remove @):

```
http://localhost/username
```

Comment: `echo str_replace("@","",$mention_url);`

Comment: `Str_replace('/@', '/', $url);`. $url should include $mention_url and user name ($srting)

Comment: i try with str_replace not work

Comment: How are you tryng? str_replace does not modify the original string.

$your_string = 'some string'

$another_string = str_replace('o', 'a', $your_string);

$your_string is still 'some string', whereas $another_string is 'same string'

Comment: See http://ideone.com/89Ukav

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use this also it is working. I have tested it here-- https://regex101.com/r/jqPsfL/1

```
$da = "http://localhost/@username";
echo preg_replace("/\/\@(\w+)/","/$1",$da);
```

I think your default data is

```
http://localhost/@username
```

and you want to remove @. So, solution is based on that. If I did not understand your problem. Please can you explain what do you want.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$WebsiteURL = 'http://www.walla.co.il';
$string = "@username";   
$string = preg_replace("/@([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/", "<a href='$WebsiteURL/$1'>$0</a>", $string);
```

Comment: Please expand your answer to explain how it answers the question. Code dump answers are not preferred.